# How to call a non-class function from a class method?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to call the `sh` method from [FileUtils](https://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils/sh).

```
class A
  def self.method
    sh('echo hello')
  end
end

def function
  sh('echo hello')
end

function # this is fine
A.method # this gives an error
```

The error I get is
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'sh' for A:Class`
How can I change my method to be able to call the function?

Comment: What Ruby version? This code runs fine for me on Ruby 2.7.

Comment: Maybe the problem is because the function I'm trying to call is from a library. I'll edit my question to include the details.

Comment: I thought `FileUtils.sh` was deprecated some time ago; using backticks or `%x(...)` should both work. It's not in Ruby 2.5 or 3.

Comment: Yes it does say it's deprecated, and I will switch to use a new method. But it's still confusing why I can call it from a non-class method but not a class method.

Comment: I don't see how you can call it at *all* in a pure Ruby environment, but you still haven't said what version of Ruby you're running.

Comment: ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]

Comment: @sam_phillips_1628534640 In a just-Ruby environment w/ no Gems? I still don't understand how, although it's not worth firing up the Windows machine to test. It's still in Rake AFAIK, but AFAICT it's been out of Ruby core since 2.2.something